# Call phone or open email client from Material UI TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, anchor

I have a MaterialUI `TextField` component, which is some circumstances is disabled and clickable to go to a phone number or email. When this is the case, I want to be able to click on the input and have it behave like an anchor tag with an href, which does not seem  to be an option.

Here is the a rough example of what the code looks like:

```js
<TextField
    value={phone}
    onClick={() => {
        console.warn(`Behave like an href to ${phone}`);
    }}
/>

OR

<TextField
    value={phone}
    href={`tel:${phone}`}
/>
```

I need to know either how to allow `TextField` to accept and href or how to get the `onClick` button to behave like an href. What is the proper way of doing so?

Here is a functional [sample app of what I am doing with the features I am missing pointed out](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-fire-y98v0?file=/src/App.js:330-613)

Comment: I've been making changes to codesandbox for quite some time now but I can't think of a proper solution. However, it is a very interesting topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href`. If you need the MUI `Link` component, you could extract a `TextFieldLink` component that conditionally wraps a `TextField` with `Link` based on the `disabled` prop.

You will probably also want a `handleClick` handler that provides at least some very basic validation for `phone` and `email`.

Disclaimer, I have never used the `tel:` attribute before, but IIUC this is what you want.

```js
const { TextField, Button, Link } = MaterialUI
const { Fragment, useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('+11234567890');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('email@email.com');

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        label="Phone"
        disabled={!editMode}
        value={phone}
        onChange={(evt) => setPhone(evt.target.value)}
        onClick={() => {
          if (!editMode) {
            window.location.href = `tel:${phone}`;
          }
        }}
      />
      <TextField
        disabled={!editMode}
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(evt) => setEmail(evt.target.value)}
        onClick={() => {
          if (!editMode) {
            window.location.href = `mailto:${email}`;
          }
        }}
      />
      <Button onClick={() => setEditMode(!editMode)}>
        {editMode ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```